# Flutter :- How to sorting a custom List

Tags: sorting, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Here I want I've some listed item and I want to sort item them on its id or rating. when I click on the side drawer button it will need to rearrange the list view with sorted items hope you understand my question.

I've tried this [smooth_sort](https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_sort) package for sorting but it won't work for me because it will sort based on the index. and I want to sort based on my own value.

Here is the output image
[image]

Here is my code

```
class _MapAddressListingScreenState extends State<MapAddressListingScreen>
    with AfterLayoutMixin<MapAddressListingScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  List addressData;

  @override
  void afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context) {
    _getAddress();
  }

  _getAddress() {
    List requestedLatlong = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    print("============================Address Data");
    print(requestedLatlong);
    setState(() {
      addressData = requestedLatlong;
    });
  }

  List<Widget> _addressData() {
    List<Widget> _address = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < addressData.length; i++) {
      _address.add(
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            print('address list taped');
            AddWalkinModel model = widget.addWalkinModel;
            print("After model");
            model.fromMap = false;
            model.fromMapListing = true;
            model.autoAssign = addressData[i]['autoAssign'];
            model.branchId = addressData[i]['branchId'];
            model.branchServiceId = addressData[i]['branchServiceId'];
            print("After Model Model");
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => DynamicScreen(
                  addWalkinModel: model,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: AddressListingTile(listingTileData: addressData[i]),
        ),
      );
    }
    return _address;
  }

  Widget itemCard() {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: _addressData(),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var colorStyles = Theming.colorstyle(context);
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      backgroundColor: colorStyles['primary'],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("BSP Listview "),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.sort),
            onPressed: () {
              _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      endDrawer: Drawer(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          height: 100,
        ),
        FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              ratingSort.shuffle();
            },
            child: Text("sort")),
      ],
    ),
  ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: const Radius.circular(30.0),
                  topRight: const Radius.circular(30.0)),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          itemCard(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of sorting the widgets themselves, sort the underlying list that you are creating the widgets from.

Comment: yes, i appreciate your answer but on this page there features of sorting based on rating, distance, etc. I must need to give these features to the user

Comment: Please check the below solution and let me know in case of concern

Comment: I'll reinforce what @Abion47 pointed out and what @Ravindra Kushwaha has implied in his solution: you should use `ListView.builder()` and not `for() { address.add(aWidget) }`. By forcing the UI to display the Widgets in a certain order (instead of allowing the ListView to show the list as it is) you're fighting against Flutter. What you should do is make ListView show the list as is, because Flutter is reactive, when you sort the underlying list it should automatically update the UI after setState() is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `sort` method of the `list` for sorting the list in the specific format as follows

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    for(int i=0;i<fields.length;i++) {
      print("BEFORE==>>> ${fields[i].rating}");
    }

    fields.sort((a, b) => a.rating.compareTo(b.rating));  ///FROM THIS LINE YOU CAN PERFORM SHORTING ACCORDING TO THE RATING BASES

    for(int i=0;i<fields.length;i++) {
      print("AFTER==>>> ${fields[i].rating}");
    }

  }
```

And i have use the my demo custom list for it

```
List<Fields> fields = [
  new Fields(
    'DEFAULT CATEGORY',
    2,
  ),
  new Fields(
    'DEFAULT CATEGORY',
    1,
  ),
  new Fields(
    'DEFAULT CATEGORY',
    5,
  ),
  new Fields(
    'DEFAULT CATEGORY',
    3,
  ),
  new Fields(
    'DEFAULT CATEGORY',
    4,
  ),
];
```

And output will be follow
[image]

Please check the full source of code for it

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutterlearningapp/colors.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _HomeScreen();
  }
}

class _HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo Scroll"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Shoring"),
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  fields.sort((a, b) => a.rating.compareTo(b.rating));

                });

              },


            ),
            Expanded(
              child:  ListView.builder
                (
                  itemCount: fields.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: new Text("Rating #${fields[index].rating}"),
                      subtitle: new Text(fields[index].title),
                    );
                  }
              ) ,
            )


          ],

        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class Fields {
  final String title;
  final int rating;

  Fields(this.title, this.rating);
}

List<Fields> fields = [
  new Fields(
    'Two',
    2,
  ),
  new Fields(
    'One',
    1,
  ),
  new Fields(
    'DEFAULT CATEGORY',
    5,
  ),
  new Fields(
    'Three',
    3,
  ),
  new Fields(
    'Four',
    4,
  ),
];
```

And above output of the program as follow

[image]

Comment: okay ravindra ive checked your answer but it will just sort value i want to sort ma whole widget.

Comment: Widget will be short according to your list, you just need to ***setState** when ever you are shoring the list , your listview will be updated soon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213475/discussion-between-rutvik-gumasana-and-ravindra-kushwaha).

Comment: Happy to help you bro :), keep  happy coding